# Should one report the output of valgrind to less developers?

Tags: less

I found that in Linux Mint, the command `valgrind less` outputs

```
still reachable: 22,499 bytes in 31 blocks
```

Is that a bug? Should one report this kind of issues to the developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory identified as “still reachable” by Valgrind is memory which was allocated, *not* leaked, but not freed before the program exited. In many cases that’s fine, and the developers are relying on program exit for cleanup.

It’s only worth reporting if the value is very large, or grows with time in ways which don’t reflect expectations (*e.g.* in `less`’s case, are much larger than the size of the data being displayed).

If Valgrind identifies significant amounts of memory as “definitely lost”, that’s a different matter, and might be worth reporting — it would be especially problematic in long-running programs (which isn’t `less`’s common usage).